# ng-init parse syntax error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ejs

I run this

```
res.render('NamesPieChart',{ChartLabels : JSON.stringify(["January","February","March","April","May","June"]), DataList : JSON.stringify(datalist), title : "test"});
```

I can get the datalist with no issues. However, the ChartLabels I get the error:

```
Syntax Error: Token ',' is an unexpected token at column 47 of the expression [m_datalist=[3,6,2,1,1,2];m_chartlabels=January,February,March,April,May,June] starting at [,February,March,April,May,June].
```

It is like it doesn't see it as a string.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure, you need `JSON.stringify()` when passing the values?

Comment: please provide full code context

Comment: I just have the JSON.stringify() because it is something they had on their example.

Answer (score 0):

The code that works for me to import ng-init is:

`ng-init= "m_datalist=<%-DataList%>;m_chartlabels=<%=ChartLabels%>">`